# Could not find or load main class while opening .JAR using CMD | Gradle | Intellij-idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

**Мучаюсь уже не один день**. Где-то лежит небольшая маленькая ошибка и из-за неё вот ничего не получаеться...

Создал проект используя **Intellij-idea** -> **Gradle**. Создал один класс и в нём создал метод `public static void main(String[] args)`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее в Project Structure добавил артефакт.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сбилдил .JAR файл и попытался, используя CMD, запустить приложение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*UPD: Если прописать это: `java -jar F*Polytechnic.jar` ошибка такая: `no main manifest attribute`.*

Build Gradle:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

MANIFEST.MF:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

.JAR открыл архивом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Билдил артефакт таким образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте добавить package

Comment: Добавил package, обновил манифест, билд.. Аналогично

Comment: Очевидно проблема где то в сборке. Откройте ваш jar файл любым архиватором и посмотрите что там в итоге у вас собралось (посмотрите какие классы там есть). Плюс опишите процесс того как вы собираете ваш проект.

Comment: Окей, добавил в описание это всё)

Comment: @RomanShubenko, как уже написали:  1. должен быть `пакет` у класса.  2.`jar { manifest { attributes{ / / } } }`.  3.секция, как в ответе.  4. удалите каталог META-INF из java каталога, он будет генерироваться автоматически и добавляться в jar.  5. и не нужно создавать артефакт из среды, если есть среда сборки - `gradle jar ` произведет при необходимости компиляцию и создание jar файла

Answer (score 1):

B build.gradle допиши
  `jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'com.example.demo.DemoApplication'
        )
    }
}`

Comment: Я добавлял уже класс в пакет, но потом я всё откатил обратно - аналогичная ситуация даже с пакетом.

Answer (score 0):

```
java -classpath ваш_джарник.jar пакет.НазваниеЗапускаемогоКласса
```

Comment: `no main manifest attribute` тогда

Comment: Да, я ошибся, -jar это когда Main-Class в манифесте указан. Исправил ответ